# Spring @ResponseBody view resolution

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

## Question

Have anyone figured out an alternative means of view resolution for `@ResponseBody` (to allow implementing part of what [`ConcentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) does) ?

## Reasoning

The spring view resolution mechanism is very powerful, in particular with [`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html), allowing view resolution e.g., on path extensions (`foo.json`) or request parameters (`?view=json`).

However, when using `@ResponseBody` annotation the view resolution chain is bypassed. With [`mvc:annotation-driven`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) we get a [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) instead, with view resolution which seems to be based solely on the `Accept`header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the heroes at Spring already noticed this issue by [#SPR-8410](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8410) and [#SPR-7517](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7517).

> This is now resolved. To configure, declare a ContentNegotiationManager bean with a ParameterContentNeogiationStrategy and use it in turn to configure RequestMappingHandlerMapping, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.

Fix versions `3.2 M2`.